# React Router - Change Component when clicking on list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have list items with Artists names. I want to be able to switch to my "AlbumsList" component when clicking on any artist name. The route will also hold the artist id. However, when I click, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const ArtistList = (props) => {

  // console.log(props.list);

  let items = props.list.map(x => {
    return(
        <Link to={`/albums/${x.artistId}`}>
        <li key={x.artistId} className="artist-items">{x.artistName}</li>
        </Link>
      );
  });

  return(
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {items}
          </ul>
          <Route path="/albums/:id" Component={AlbumList}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try `return(
        
        <li key={x.artistId} className="artist-items"><Link to={\`/albums/${x.artistId}\`}>{x.artistName}
        </Link></li>
      );`

Comment: It still does the same thing :(

Comment: are you getting any error like. Cannot read property map of undefined

Comment: No error, it just shows the route path in the browser with the corresponding artist id but it doesn't route to the album list component.

Comment: Try to make use of withRouter `export default withRouter(ArtistList)`